# How to avoid full table scan in sql

Tags: sql, db2

```
    SELECT 
      DISTINCT P.IDENTIFICATIONNUM IDNUMBER, 
      P.NAME NAME, 
      P.NATIONALITY NATIONALITY, 
      O.NAME COMPANY
    FROM APPLICANT_TB P
    LEFT JOIN APP_TB A ON A.APPLICANTID=P.APPLICANTID
    LEFT JOIN ORGANISATION_TB O ON O.ORGID = A.ORGID
```

as the sql code showing, i am using IBM DB2 , and according to explain plan , all the 3 tables are full table scan .can someone tell me how to avoid this ? (all the PK using are indexed)

Comment: You're selecting every record from the table(s), how do you expect to get every record without reading (scanning) the entire table?  In general you avoid a table scan by filtering the results with a `WHERE` clause (ideally on an indexed column).  Doing so in this case would change the results of your query.

Comment: As @David say, you are asking all rows. You need to specify predicates via the WHERE clause, to filter the rows.

Comment: You say all the PKs are indexed, You also need to index all the FKs. However as you are not filtering with a where caluse this may nto spped things up as much as you would like.

Comment: Actually, the "slow" part of this query isn't likely the full table scan (which is essentially unavoidable in this case), it's probably the use of `DISTINCT`.  You _may_ be able to improve things by knocking out duplicate records first (if they exist).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Be more selective with the records you want. Include a WHERE clause.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are selecting all the rows the most efficient way to return those to you is to do table scans.

Even if you add filters you still may do table scans, that will depend on how well your indexes match to the columns you are filtering on, and how up-to-date the database statistics are.

In general the query optimizer will guess the percentage of the table it needs based on you filter. Once that percentage goes over a certain (surprisingly small like 20%) portion of the table, it will choose a table scan as the "best" way to get the data you are asking for.

Comment: that mean's even I use indexed column in my "where" clause , full table scan still can happen?

Comment: It can do. If your where clause includes the majority of the table then there is little else the database can do but go through the entire table. You might be able to save a little time by using a clustered index but this will be a marginal gain.

Comment: I think going through the clustered index will be slower, you not only have to scan the index but then randomly read all or most of the records in the table, creating extra io compared to the table scan.

Comment: Frank, Yes but the optimizer is smart. So a table scan may be the best way to get the data you are asking for.  If you think you know better than the optimizer you can try adding optimizer hints to you query (if db2 supports them).